# How to retain newly added values on a two-dimensional array (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck at this part of my program. These are 2 options for my Student Information System (not using GUI/JOption and without linking to a database. I already have a 2-dimensional array (String records[][] = new String [5][3];) that has the first 2 "rows" ([0][0] to [0][2] and [1][0] to [1][2]) filled up with pre-assigned data (First Name, Last Name, Course).
If you look below, the part where "b" or "B" option is selected, this is for adding new values to a new array (incremented so that when option B is used, it will assign first [2][0], then [3][0]
 and so on). It seemed to work since it does show that all the data I've entered was added and is displayed in the proper order. THE PROBLEM IS: when I choose 'Y" to return to the top menu and select option A to VIEW the newly added record (using ID number 2), it shows that it contains all "null". Is there something I've missed? This is the missing step I need in order to finish this program. Thanks ahead for the help.

```
 if("a".equals(option1)|| "A".equals(option1)){
        System.out.println("Please enter the Student ID for the record to view.");
        String a = reader1.readLine();
        idcheck = Integer.parseInt(a);
        x1=idcheck;
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        System.out.print(records[x1][y] + " ");
        }            

        System.out.println("\nReturn to Main Menu or Exit? (Y/N)");
        cont1= reader1.readLine(); 
    }
    else if("b".equals(option1)||"B".equals(option1)){
        arr_count++;
        for (int y = 0; y<3;y++){
        System.out.println("Enter Value for "+ option [y]+":"  ); 
        String X = reader1.readLine();
        records[arr_count][y] = X;            
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to add the code of reader as the error could be there.

Comment: Here's the reader code:
BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
My continue option after each if-else is a do-while

Comment: You can troubleshoot this yourself by printing out `idcheck` and `x1` and `X` to see if they all have valid values in every case. This can help you determine when the `null` values appear without having to step through a debugger.

Comment: idcheck depends on what the user enters in option A. x1 just holds that same value to simplify the for-loop. x just reads what value the user enters to add in the array in option B.

Comment: well there is still not enough code to see why your getting a null